# initForReadingWithData is deprecated - initForReadingFromData returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated, nskeyedunarchiver

I have the following warning (Xcode 10.1 - iOS 12.1)

> 'initForReadingWithData:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Use -initForReadingFromData:error: instead*

When I'm change the method to initForReadingFromData, the NSKeyedUnarchiver returns nil.

```
// Current code which produces the warning (but works fine) : 

NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];

NSMutableArray *loadedCredentialIdentities = (NSMutableArray *)[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kStoredCredentialIdentities];

[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

...

```
// using initForReadingFromData produces no warning (but doesn't work - loadedCredentialIdentities is nil) : 


NSError *error = nil;
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver    alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:&error];

NSMutableArray *loadedCredentialIdentities = (NSMutableArray *)[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kStoredCredentialIdentities];

[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

Comment: Print `error` if `unarchiver` is nil.

Comment: unarchiver is not nil ... and there is no error - error is nil

Answer (score 7):

Turning off secureCoding solved the problem.

```
[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:&error];
```

**`unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = NO;`**

```
[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:...]
```

In cases you don't have to be backward compatible it's better not to turn off secureCoding

Answer (score 1):

It because you are using `decodeObjectForKey`. If you don't set `requiresSecureCoding` to `NO`, you must use [decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder/1442558-decodeobjectofclass?language=objc) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video from WWDC 2018 and then fix your unarchivers to use secure coding:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/222/